# Money transfer from Australia to India - avoid receiving ends service tax

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, australia, services

How to avoid service tax at receiving bank in India

Answer (score 2):

All Bank fees were included in the service tax ambit [For example Check bounce, issue of duplicate statement, fees charged for remittance etc]. However as quite a few Banks structured the Remittance Business to show less charges and cover the difference in the Fx rate involved, the Govt has redone the service tax and one needs to pay Rs 120 for an amount of Rs 100,000. 
There is no way to avoid service tax on remittance if you are using a remittance service.